# How can I map the fetched data from the api?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Basically, I have a search page component which displays the search results of the query that the user typed in the input field.

This is the file.

```
"use client";

import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import useFetch from "../hooks/useFetch";
import ProductCard from "@/components/ProductCard";

const SearchPage = () => {
  const search = useSearchParams();
  const searchQuery = search ? search?.get("q") : null;
  const encodedSearchQuery = encodeURI(searchQuery || "");

  const { data } = useFetch(
    `/products?populate*=&filters[title][$contains]=${encodedSearchQuery}`
  );
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
         {/* {data?.map((product) => (
          <ProductCard key={product.id} products={product} />
        ))} */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchPage;
```

I am using a global hook useFetch for it.
I am able to see the filtered data in the console as well.
Productcard component is basically for structure and it takes a prop called products

I tried mapping with the commented out code but it shows me these errors.

This is useFetch.tsx

In this snippet, I have a utility function called fetchData that is responsible for making API requests. It uses Axios to make the request and includes an authorization header.

```
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { fetchData } from "@/app/utils/api";

const useFetch = (endpoint: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDataFromApi = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetchData(endpoint);
        setData(res);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchDataFromApi();
  }, [endpoint]);

  return { data };
};

export default useFetch;
```

Property 'map' does not exist on type 'never'.
Parameter 'product' implicitly has an 'any' type.

I actually saw someone do it exactly the same way but with Javascript.
I am using typescript, I am new to it. How should I do it with typescript?

I can show more components related to it if someone wants to see that.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is `useFetch` a custom hook? Or from React? https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-fetch. If same as react you can use `useFetch<Type>` to add the type of the response

Comment: @Hoopra I edited the question to include the useFetch.tsx now. Thank you for your query btw!!!

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I might still need the definition for `fetchData` too

Answer (score 0):

So the issue you're having is connected with TypeScript part of it. When fetching the data I believe you are getting back an `any` from the `fetchData` and the type your `res` is `any`.

But the core issue is your `useState` declaration. You're initializing it to `null`, so when you try to access `data?.anyMethod()` it is going to be `never`, and it will gives out *"Property 'map' does not exist on type 'never'"*.

You can use [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) with `useState` (which itself is a generic function) to let TypeScript know what kind of data it is going to store, in your case you can create a type for your product:

```
interface Product {
 id: number;
 name: string;
 ...
}
```

and hand it over to `useState` generic in your case as I guess you're expecting an array of products, it should be:

```
 const [data, setData] = useState<Product[] | null>(null);

  
  useEffect(() => {
  ...
```

But as your `useFetch` function itself is reusable one I'd advice you to make it a generic one itself, so you can pass the type when calling it and expect to receive it. You can achieve this doing so:

```
const useFetch = <T,>(endpoint: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T | null>(null);
  ...
}
```

And after when calling it you just pass the type:

```
const { data } = useFetch<Product[]>(
    `/products?populate*=&filters[title][$contains]=${encodedSearchQuery}`
  );
```

Comment: I never said `null` has a type `never`, but the TS sees `never`when you try to access `.map` on null. More implicitly when you call use it with a question like `data?.map()` as it can never be true, so the type of `data?` becomes `never`

Comment: If you believe you're right, I'll remove my comments. All I wanted was to let you know I don't think you're right and I have achieved that. Have a great day!

Comment: Ok, maybe I worded it a bit wrong, what I meant was that it becomes a never when you try it with `data?.anyFunction` because null will become `never`. I'll go on and fix it, thanks for the comment.